# Problems with GO keyword

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, dynamic-sql

I have a query:

```
DECLARE @str NVARCHAR(max)
SET @str = 'SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON' + CHAR(13)+ CHAR(10) + 'GO' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'Select 1 from MyTable'
PRINT @str
EXEC (@str)
```

It returns an error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2 `Incorrect syntax near 'GO'`.

But if I exec the printed query in a new query editor it works fine.

I am using SQL Server 2014.

Comment: If you get rid of the GO, it will work.

Comment: I realy need a "GO" in my dynamic SQL statement. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Why don't you simply prepare two separate strings and execute them one by one?  Have you tried to add a semicolon after `ON`?

Comment: @ArtashesKhachatryan, why do you need a `GO`?  It is not required in your example.  GO implies separate batches and therefore requires dynamic SQL statements to be executed separately.  Maybe we can help if you provide your use-case.

Comment: GO is not part of T-SQL, it is just the statement separator in SSMS and can be even changed in the settings